# AST: get leaf value when leafs are of different types

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to represent in a AST a structure like this:

```
struct {
  int data;
  double doubleDataArray[10];
  struct {
    int nestedData;
  };
};
```

I'm creating an AST like this one:

[image]

I need to retrieve data from leaves. The problem that I have is that leaves contains heterogenous data. A leaf can represent an integer value, a double, a string and so on.

I can create classes like `IntValue`, `DoubleValue` that inherit from `Value` and store respective data, perform a `dynamic_cast` to convert `Value` to the type referred in its `type` attribute. Something like

```
switch (value->getType()) {
  case Type::Int: {
   auto iv = dynamic_cast<IntValue>(value);
   int value = iv->getValue();
  } break;
  case Type::Double() {
   auto dv = dynamic_cast<DoubleValue>(value);
   double value = dv->getValue();
  } break;
  //…
}
```

but I'd like to know if there's a better way, because a switch like that one it's not easy maintainable and readable.

I've seen some example, like in `boost::program_options`, something like:

```
int value = value->getValue().as<int>();
```

It's a better way? How can I reproduce this?

Comment: Regarding your last code piece, you can use std::any for that

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow your design but it looks like the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#C++_example) might be useful.

Comment: Your question is not clear and there are multiple solution for type conversion, statically and dynamically! Please add some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this using c++17

```
struct node {
    //... other stuff
    std::variant</*your types of nodes here*/> type;
}
```

then call this visitor on your nodes

```
std::visit([](auto&& node) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(node)>, /* your type here */>) {
        // ...
    }
    else if constexpr(/* ... */) {
        // ...
    }
}, node0.type);
```

Answer (score 1):

Going on a tangent for a slightly different flavor of a solution, how about doing it the way [capnproto](https://capnproto.org/) does it? Capnproto's own schema compiler represents the AST in memory using the Capnproto wire encoding. The schema supports tagged unions. The lexer and parser for the schema are built using combinators (although I presume that you already have a good parser in place that produces the AST).

The structure could be expressed as follows using capnp schema:

```
# MyAst.capnp

struct Struct {
  fields @0 :List(Field);
}

struct Field {
  name @4 :Text;
  union {
    integer @0 :List(Int32);
    fpoint @1 :List(Double);
    text @2 :List(Text);
    structure @3 :Struct;
  }
}
```

The schema compiler would generate C++ code for this, with the following important classes `Struct::Reader`, `Struct::Builder`, `Field::Reader` and `Field::Builder`. Whatever makes the AST would use the `Struct::Builder` type to make a structure instance, with its data. Then, you'd traverse the structure as follows:

```
void processData(Struct::Reader reader) {
  auto fields = reader.getFields();
  for (auto &field : fields) {
    if (field.hasInteger()) {
      int32_t val = field.getInteger();
      ...
    } else if (field.hasFpoint()) {
      double val = field.getFpoint();
      ...
    } else if (field.hasText()) {
      kj::StringPtr val = field.getText();
      ...
    } else if (field.hasStructure()) {
      processData(field.getStructure());
    }
  }
}
```

The `kj` framework (included in capnproto) has quite a few compiler-building goodies, such as memory arenas. A `Foo::Builder` would then be obtained from an `Orphan<Foo>`, and the orphan is produced by an orphanage that carves out memory from an arena allocator. With your entire AST built in an arena with one or few large, contiguous segments, this would perform better than allocating all those types on general-purpose heap (assuming that your AST is not tiny). This representation also serializes directly to disk or network with no transcoding: you can do a binary dump of an orphanage's arena, then later load it directly and you get all your data back with zero effort and zero transcoding. The `Foo::Reader` and `Foo::Builder` types provide very fast accessors that don't do any data decoding nor translation - that's the advantage of the capnproto encoding. If you modify the data in the AST, the orphanage may grow, but it also provides a copy operation that copies only the referenced areas (a copying GC, if you will) - and that's blazing fast, too, since no transcoding is done. Chunks of verbatim binary data are copied with very little traversal overhead.

Comment: It seems pretty nice, I'll spend some effort in order to study it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that since you're into realtime systems, Capnproto would be of plenty interest. It has zero transcoding overhead, small memory overhead, and its RPC protocol is also designed to minimize the number of roundtrips. I'm using Capnproto in defining an interface to a realtime system, and it's great for that. The generated code is small, and negligible compared to e.g. messagepack or protobufs.